# BitmapFactory decode returns null

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am dealing with a weird thing in android now. My code that used to work till a few days ago stops working. 
I am selecting an image from gallery and want to get the Bitmap object of it.
My code:

```
 imgDecodableString = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160114_141351594.jpg"

 Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
 Log.d(Constants.TAG, "decodedBitmap: " + decodedBitmap);
```

Bitmap is now null (used to work) and I really don't get what is wrong. Didn't changed my code. Does anyone had this problem? Thank you.

I do have the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: if you are using android 6.0 than you need to runtime permission of write external storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (CheckPermission(youractivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
// you have permission go ahead

String  imgDecodableString = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160114_141351594.jpg";

if(new File(imgDecodableString).exists()){
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
Log.d("Tag", "decodedBitmap: " + decodedBitmap);}
} else {
// you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
RequestPermission(youractivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (permsRequestCode) {

        case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                // you do not have permission show toast.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                Permission)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Permission},
                    Code);
        }
    }
}

public boolean CheckPermission(Activity context, String Permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In androidmainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the comment from first line, it should look like this

```
imgDecodableString = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160114_141351594.jpg"

Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
Log.d(Constants.TAG, "decodedBitmap: " + decodedBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code:

```
if(imgDecodableString.exists()){
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
Log.d(Constants.TAG, "decodedBitmap: " + decodedBitmap);}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Are you using marshmallow version ?